# Accesing C functions in Cython

Tags: c, cython

i am trying to use C code in cython

example.c:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 double* reverseCoeffs(double* coeffs, int N) {
    double *revCoeffs = (double*) malloc(7 * sizeof(double));
    if (N < 7) {
       coeffs = (double *) realloc(coeffs, 7 * sizeof(double));
       while (N < 7) coeffs[N++] = (double) 0;
    }
    // The first coefficient is the linear part
    revCoeffs[0] = 1 / coeffs[0];
    revCoeffs[1] = -coeffs[1] / pow(coeffs[0], 3);
    revCoeffs[2] = (2 * pow(coeffs[1], 2) - coeffs[0] * coeffs[2]) / pow(coeffs[0], 5);
    free(coeffs);
    return revCoeffs;
}
```

This works perfectly fine in C but when i use it in cython it throws an error.

example.pyx:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cdef extern from "reverseCoeffs.c":
  double* reverseCoeffs(double* coeffs, int N)
def cisr(np.ndarray[np.double_t,ndim=1] x, int N):
  cdef double* x_data = <double *>x.data
  cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] res
  res = reverseCoeffs(x_data, N)
  return res
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
running build_ext
cythoning test.pyx to test.c

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef extern from "test.c":
    double* reverseCoeffs(double* coeffs, int N)
def cisr(np.ndarray[np.double_t,ndim=1] x, int N):
cdef double* x_data = <double *>x.data
cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1] res
res = reverseCoeffs(x_data, N)
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:8:21: Cannot convert 'double *' to Python object
building 'pang' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-      prototypes -fPIC -I/home/sulabh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include  -I/home/sulabh/include/ -I/home/sulabh/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c test.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/test.o
test.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython   compilation.
```

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: You are returning a double, not a pointer to a double which is what you have defined in your function prototype, which are not the same.

Either return a pointer to a double OR change your function to return a double.

Comment: when i remove pointer it throws error...error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected...moreover how can i return a pointer to double

Comment: @SulabhTiwari: If you get an error message, please copy-paste the entire error message with file names and line numbers.

Comment: @SulabhTiwari: It's impossible for Cython to know the number of elements in the `res` array (7), because the `reverseCoeffs` function doesn't return it. Please consult the the numpy + Cython documentation about returning an `np.ndarray` properly.

Comment: @SulabhTiwari: Your call to `realloc` is unnecessary, `malloc` has already allocated an array of 7 `double`s.

Comment: @pts complete error posted and yes i would like to consult the documentation .but still if you have idea how would it be like to return revCoeffs

Comment: @pts Or do you have any link where they give more examples of exporting C function into cython..Probably examples will help more to understand

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the details of numpy + Cython. If someone else knows, it will be easy for them to answer now, based on the full error message you have posted.